# DATA-TITLE ON CAKEPHP

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Is it possible to put the html5 data-title in the input by cakephp ?
If yes, could someone give me an example of how to accomplish this in the view part?

I tried something like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->categories('category_id', $categories, ['data-title' => '<?php $categories->description ?>', 'class' => 'tree table  table-hover ', 'id' => 'tree']); ?>
```

But it did not work.
Ps.: I've already searched the documentation and haven't found anything that helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible:

```
<?= $this->Form->control('category_id',['data-title' => $categories->description, 'class' => 'tree table  table-hover ', 'id' => 'tree']); ?>
```

> I've already searched the documentation and haven't found anything that helps me.

Id you need data attributes for options read this **https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#using-collections-to-build-options**